# Assigning foreign key constraints in tmap

Tags: talend

I'm learning Talend tools and I'm migrating an Access db to Postgresql, I can handle primary keys and 'is null' but I can't figure out how to put in foreign keys/constraints. Is there any guide for this? Or can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the foreign keys while creating the table? I do not understand as of how you want to create keys in tMap, which is just that - a mapping component.

Comment: appologies, I should rephrase the question: If I'm using Talend to migrate a Access db to Postgresql can I enforce the foreign key constraints or do I have to reconstruct them on the Postgresql side?